# Java Stream throws java.lang.TypeNotPresentException

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following Problem. I have an array of Strings representing email addresses and i want to convert the strings to another Type. To do this i am using Java Streams.

```
final List<String> recipientsStrings = Arrays.asList("test@mail.com", "test2@mail.com")
final InternetAddress[] to = (InternetAddress[]) recipientsStrings
            .stream()
            .map(this::createInternetAddress)
            .toArray();
```

and the signature of createInternetAddress is:

```
private InternetAddress createInternetAddress(final String address)
```

The Problem is, that the map function is throwing a java.lang.TypeNotPresentException. The strange thing is, that if i write a lambda function instead of a method reference it works. So my question is what is the difference between the following pieces of code.

```
.map(this::createInternetAddress)
```

and

```
.map(mail -> this.createInternetAddress(mail))
```

Comment: When you encounter an exception, you should include the full stacktrace. Does you `createInternetAddress` method have annotations?

Comment: Maybe specify java version as well, I am getting `ClassCastException` on 17 with both syntax.

Comment: So you did not get a `TypeNotPresentException` but a `ClassCastException` and you did not get it at the `map` function but after the `toArray()` completed and the change between method reference and lambda expression also didn’t affect the outcome. Impressive, how many wrong information you managed to provide in one question…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With both signatures, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [LInternetAddress; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [LInternetAddress; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Either lambda function or method reference is equivalent, your issue is with the casting `(InternetAddress[])`, to solve this you can simply use:

```
final InternetAddress[] to = recipientsStrings
        .stream()
        .map(this::createInternetAddress)
        .toArray(InternetAddress[]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it seems like you are right. When i was debugging the problem i was only running the code without the casting.